# Appending values to the array is duplicating it

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, append

I'm running the k-means algorithm 3 times and storing the final centers in an array

```
center_array = []
backXnorm=Xnorm
for i in range(1,3):
    X=dataML
    X = X[np.random.default_rng(seed=i).permutation(X.columns.values)] 
    print(X.head())  
    Xnorm=mms.fit_transform(X)         
    km=KMeans(n_clusters=4,n_init=10,max_iter=30,random_state=42)    
    y_kmeans=km.fit_predict(Xnorm)
    center_array.append(km.cluster_centers_)
```

The values are being duplicated, as it seems that the entire array is added again in each iteration.
Below you have the output I'm getting.

```
[array([[ 0.91902229,  0.99146416,  0.11154588, -0.41348193, -0.45307083,
         0.18579957,  0.20004497, -0.91902229, -0.17537297, -0.99146416,
        -0.4091783 , -0.12493111],
       [-0.17637011, -0.02577591, -0.48222273,  1.39450598,  1.50699298,
        -0.14651225, -0.12975152,  0.17637011,  0.65213679,  0.02577591,
         1.37195399,  0.44572744],
       [ 0.91902229, -1.00860933,  0.11367937, -0.40910528, -0.45108061,
         0.19771608,  0.23722015, -0.91902229, -0.18480587,  1.00860933,
        -0.40459059, -0.13536744],
       [-1.08811289, -0.0290917 ,  0.19925625, -0.46264585, -0.48998741,
        -0.14748408, -0.1943812 ,  1.08811289, -0.23289607,  0.0290917 ,
        -0.45219009, -0.14996175]]), array([[-0.17537297,  0.18579957, -0.91902229, -0.99146416,  0.99146416,
        -0.41348193, -0.45307083, -0.4091783 , -0.12493111,  0.11154588,
         0.91902229,  0.20004497],
       [ 0.65213679, -0.14651225,  0.17637011,  0.02577591, -0.02577591,
         1.39450598,  1.50699298,  1.37195399,  0.44572744, -0.48222273,
        -0.17637011, -0.12975152],
       [-0.18480587,  0.19771608, -0.91902229,  1.00860933, -1.00860933,
        -0.40910528, -0.45108061, -0.40459059, -0.13536744,  0.11367937,
         0.91902229,  0.23722015],
       [-0.23289607, -0.14748408,  1.08811289,  0.0290917 , -0.0290917 ,
        -0.46264585, -0.48998741, -0.45219009, -0.14996175,  0.19925625,
        -1.08811289, -0.1943812 ]])]
```

I was expecting the final array to be something like this

```
[[ 0.91902229,  0.99146416,  0.11154588, -0.41348193, -0.45307083,
         0.18579957,  0.20004497, -0.91902229, -0.17537297, -0.99146416,
        -0.4091783 , -0.12493111],
       [-0.17637011, -0.02577591, -0.48222273,  1.39450598,  1.50699298,
        -0.14651225, -0.12975152,  0.17637011,  0.65213679,  0.02577591,
         1.37195399,  0.44572744],
       [ 0.91902229, -1.00860933,  0.11367937, -0.40910528, -0.45108061,
         0.19771608,  0.23722015, -0.91902229, -0.18480587,  1.00860933,
        -0.40459059, -0.13536744],
       [-1.08811289, -0.0290917 ,  0.19925625, -0.46264585, -0.48998741,
        -0.14748408, -0.1943812 ,  1.08811289, -0.23289607,  0.0290917 ,
        -0.45219009, -0.14996175]]
```

Am I using the append wrong? Should I use another typpe of structure to store the final centers values?

Comment: I am not sure If you are aware what you doing or I am missing something.
What I can see you do in the loop:
1. Shuffle the columns in the input data (X)
2. Calculate the `cluster_centers_`
3. Add the centers to the array.

And you end up with array containing the same centers but shuffled.

Comment: @K4liber I'm doing the shuffle because k-means is sensitive about columns order

Comment: Why do think that k-means is sensitive about columns order? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47606847/6718081

Answer (score 0):

K-means is not sensitive about columns order. That is why you get the same results but shuffled according to the shuffle of the columns.